# Error: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [SqlMapConfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: apache-camel, mybatis, filenotfoundexception, mybatis-sql

**Background**:

- I'm working on apache camel project and trying to use myBatis (camel-mybatis) for DB query purposes.
- But when I try to deploy the bundle in KARAF, it prompts the below error,

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Error when instantiating bean nfs-sqlSessionFactory of class org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.wrapAsCompDefEx(BeanRecipe.java:361)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstanceFromFactory(BeanRecipe.java:297)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:278)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:830)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:811)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:255)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:186)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:724)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:411)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:276)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:300)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:269)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:265)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:255)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1103)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:695)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:483)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4403)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2092)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1243)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1215)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1205)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:501)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:355)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:307)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [SqlMapConfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:171)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:361)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:492)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor228.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:299)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:980)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstanceFromFactory(BeanRecipe.java:295)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    ... 32 more
```

- But I have included this resource file in the classpath as below,

[image]

- How can I resolve this error? Appreciate your thoughts and comments.

Thank You